# Is there an SDK to write console apps to simulate an Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: c#, xbox360, controllers

Is there any SDK I can use to write a console app that can connect to an Xbox 360 as a controller and simulate controller interaction?

Comment: So, you want to connect your PC via USB to an xbox 360 and have the xbox think a normal controller is plugged in (being controlled by your program)?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Yes, exactly. Although, it doesn't have to be via USB, could be bluetooth etc.

Comment: Bluetooth is out, I think. The wireless controllers use a custom protocol.

Comment: The protocol is encrypted on the wire with special hardware - although it was cracked in 2010, you probably won't have much luck faking it for practical use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly have a turnkey answer to your question, but a [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) would be an ideal piece of hardware to use to simulate input.

It can act as a USB Host or Device and you can program it to appear as any Device.

You could easy capture and replay controller USB traffic to have repeatable input, or go the route of scripting the events yourselves. Unfortunately, I don't know of any existing project to do so.